# How to custom registration in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to custom register function in Laravel 5.2, before it was in the `postRegister()` function in Laravel 5.2 but there is more that function.
I wanted to know how?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want add custom attribute when user register, see first answer via @Achraf.

If you want send confirmation email, this should works:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
    // override default register method
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        // Sending email, sms or doing anything you want
        $this->activationService->sendActivationMail($user);

        return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'We sent a comfirmation email to your email, please click on link inside before login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

'but there is more that function?' i dont realy understand what u mean

anyway check this
[LARAVEL API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.html)

and here is a little exemple i hope it helps :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Userinfo;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }        
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'country' => 'required|max:255',
            'zip' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
         $user =  User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            ]);
       $userinfo =  Userinfo::create([
           'user_id' => $user->id,
           'address' => $data['address'],
           'address2' => $data['address2'],
           'city' => $data['city'],
           'zip' => $data['zip'],
           'country' => $data['country'],
           'phone' => $data['phone'],
            ]);
        return ($user);
}
}
```

as ou can see i have 2 tables, user and userinfos

Check this exemple , it should help you
  [->TAKE ME TO REDEMPTION](https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-example)

This tutorial will help too
 [->potatos](http://bensmith.io/email-verification-with-laravel)

Comment: I like you code. But i want send verification mail to user after register. I thought the overloaded function `postRegister(Request $request)` but is not work.

Comment: i edited my answer , check the link bellow , it should help you, its a ready exemple of what you want to do